# How to determine why application is prompting for elevation

Tags: windows-7, uac, elevation

When launching my executable, Windows is prompting for elevation, when it shouldn't be.

How can i figure out *why* Windows is prompting me to elevate my executable on launch?

**Notes:**

- there is **no** manifest resource (asking for `asAdministrator`, or otherwise)
- there is **no** manifest file
- the compatibilty tab (for all users and just me) has the "Run as administrator" not checked

How can i determine why my application is prompting for elevation?

Comment: Is there any file I/O operation that requires administrative access? (On Windows/Program Files folders), Registry?

Comment: What your code tries to do will NEVER cause elevation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the absence of a manifest, the usual reasons are name heuristics (eg your file is called setup.exe) and group policy (which you may have set accidentally after a "this program may not have run as expected" dialog.)

To prevent it, simply apply a manifest (embedded or external) with asInvoker. Then you will no longer care about these heuristic and you will not elevate.

I know I commented this above but I need to repeat it: What your code tries to do will NEVER cause elevation. NEVER. Stuff that won't work unless you're elevated fails when you're not elevated. It doesn't elevate you.

Comment: Damnest thing was that i created an external `MyApp.exe.manifest` file, declaring `asInvoker`, and it still prompts. Yet i rename the executable, and it no longer does. i'm still hoping to find a log somewhere of *why* Windows thinks the app needs elevation (manifested `requireAdministrator`, user compatibility request, all users compatibility request, setup heuristic detection, and "miscellaneous")

Comment: Probably compat request, associated with the name so that changing the name broke the request. I wouldn't be surprised if they outweighed manifests. You could play around with that a little to establish the "pecking order" - I haven't seen it written anywhere.